# How can I create 3 fields (columns) from 15 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that I need to clean and parse out. The top half is the "original data" and the lower half is what I need the end result to look like. There could be up to 200 to 300 rows of names of the same data(top half)

- I would copy this "original data" into one tab every day.
- Run the  macro, that will create a NEW tab with the 3 cleaned columns.
- Next day, Copy next days data to the original data tab.
- Run macro and have the data append the new day at the end of yesterday.
  Ultimately, creating a excel sheet with all the days added for each person.

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure how to start this one because of the way this data is structured. I know there is a way but I am still learning VBA and usually start with a maco recorder and then add to it. I cant seem to get this one started. Thx for any help.

Comment: At least post some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: When posting screenshots it's useful to include the column/row headers, so anyone who wanted to help out can more-easily make a start for you... Is `LastName, FirstName` in ColA for example?

Comment: Look at the pattern of the data: loop down ColA and look for an occupied cell where the rest of the row is empty (eg use `Application.CountA()`) - that's the name.  `Offset` 2 rows down from that cell to get the date, and 1 row down and 14 columns over to get the % value

Comment: Welcome to SO and... the community will get again that it is not beginner friendly, but I have to say, that your question is problematic not just because you have the typical "I don't know where to start so I need a tutorial-like answer", but your design seems also wrong: I couldn't decide from your points that you need 2 macros or only one, and because of point 2, will the number of worksheets tend to infinity day-by-day?

Answer (score 1):

Not writing this in excel, so this likely has typos, but should give you some ideas.

```vb
dim c as range, cDest as range, lr as long

set cDest = worksheets("summary").cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1) 'first paste position
Set c = worksheets("raw").range("A1") 'start search here
lr = c.entirecolumn.cells(rows.count).end(xlUp).row 'last row of data in colA

do while c.row < lr
    if len(c.value) > 0 and application.counta(c.entirerow) = 1 Then
        cDest.resize(1, 3).value = Array(c.offset(2,0).value, _
                                   c.value, c.offset(1, 14).value)
        set cdest = cdest.offset(1) ' next destination row
        set c = c.offset(3) 'skip data block
    else
        set c = c.offset(1) 'next row
    end if
loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim!  I just had to make one adjustment to the offset and it worked!!